# Swagger UI on Development Server in Net Framework 4.8

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have an older project that was built on .Net Framework 4.6.1 that we recently upgraded to 4.8. It uses MVC and WebAPI, so I installed Swashbuckle so we could use the Swagger UI for testing and seeing what APIs are available for testing. Everything works great from localhost when running in Visual Studio debug, but once moved to the server I get a 404 on the /swagger/ui page.

I know this is normal for production systems or systems without an environment variable setup, but I can't find what the trigger environment variable is for .Net Framework. I have the "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" set to "Development" and this works for .Net Core applications, but as I expected does not work for Framework.

Thank you for any pointers to fixing this little annoyance.

EDIT:

> "The Swagger UI should appear unless you've specifically coded it not
> to under some circumstance. Do you have any logic in your Startup.cs
> (or wherever you've configured Swagger) to conditionally add the
> Swagger middleware?"

This is not a core application so I don't have a startup.cs. I have a  Global.asax and 2 configuration files. I am using the standard configuration that is loaded with Swashbuckle when it's added from NuGet. The configuration is pretty standard and has no conditional loading like you would normally see in Core. Here is a snippet of the "SwaggerConfig.cs" file.

```
using Swashbuckle.Application;

[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SwaggerConfig), "Register")]
namespace App.API
{
    public class SwaggerConfig
    {
        public static void Register()
        {
            var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                .EnableSwagger(c =>
                    {
                       ....
                    }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The Swagger UI should appear unless you've specifically coded it not to under some circumstance. Do you have any logic in your Startup.cs (or wherever you've configured Swagger) to conditionally add the Swagger middleware?

Comment: @mason - I answered your question as an edit. Thank you for helping.

Comment: There were similar discussions here that may provide some help depending on your application: [Swagger UI show 404 error when I deploy it on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70813879/swagger-ui-show-404-error-when-i-deploy-it-on-iis) and [Net 6 API - 404 Not found](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/691172/net-6-api-404-not-found?sort=oldest&orderby=newest) Not sure if they will help.

Comment: @YurongDai Those are for .NET 6, not applicable for a .NET Framework setup.

Comment: You're going to need to make a [mcve]. You're just showing tiny bits to us, but we need to see a complete example that still reproduces the problem.